# How many fields are created by CPS package? Customer wants to know so that h can clear the fields

Tags: cpq, steelbrick

How many fields are created by CPS package? Customer wants to know so that h can clear the fields. Any version 14.7 and above.

Answer (score 3):

Your client doesn't need to clear any fields, because SteelBrick CPQ is a "no limits" app, meaning it can be installed even if the installation would cause the customer to exceed the maximum number of objects or fields on an object. This is true of many AppExchange apps published by various partners.